# How to retrieve value type values from generic function?

Tags: c#

I have a generic function that I am using to retrieve key-value pair value from sqlite database.

The function signature is:

```
T Retrieve<T>(string key);
```

I want to return `null` whenever the key doesn't exist in the database. I could do this for `reference types` with this signature but can't do with `value types`

I could change the signature to `object Retrieve(string key);` and then cast it to type `T` but I was wondering if there is any other better method to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are competing factors here:

- regular value-types can't be `null`
- `Nullable<T>` can be `null`, but that would be `T? Retrieve<T>(string key) where T : struct`, which would make it impossible for you to use `Retreive<string>(...)`, which seems a likely use-case

So; you can't have both of those. You way wish instead to consider reporting the result value and whether it was `null` *separately*, for example, one of:

```
bool TryRetrieve<T>(string key, out T value);
T Retrieve<T>(string key, out bool isNull);
(T value, bool isNull) Retrieve<T>(string key);
```

using `default(T)` as the value when `null` is encountered.

The advantage of the *last one* is that it also works for `async`, i.e.

```
async Task<(T value, bool isNull)> RetrieveAsync<T>(string key);
```

where-as `out` parameters do not work for most `async` scenarios.